# Is the result of adding a copy of an inequivalent category $D$ still inequivalent to $D$?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose that two categories $C$ and $D$ are inequivalent. Is the result of adding a copy of $D$ into $C$ (assume that the result is still a category), still inequivalent to $D$?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by "adding a copy into." If you just mean taking the disjoint union $C \sqcup D$, then take $D$ to be a countable discrete category (meaning there are no non-identity morphisms) and take $C$ to be a finite discrete category. Then $C \sqcup D$ is a countable discrete category and hence equivalent to $D$.

If you mean something else then you'd have to explain what that something else is.